# Validating ItemsControl in wpf didn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, validationrules

I have an ItemsControl to display translations text fields.
I want to setup validating, so if all translations are empty, there was an error, and fields was marked as "error".
Is there any possibilty to do this?

My xaml:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="LanguageItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Translations, Mode=TwoWay}"
             LostFocus="OnLostFocus" >
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="5,2,5,2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="47*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="53*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ItemLabel" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Text="{Binding Path=Key, StringFormat={x:Static res:Resources.lblCaption}}" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ItemText" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,0,22,0"
            Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, 
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"
                LostFocus="OnLostFocus"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 MaxLines="2"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     MaxLength="150">
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

My model's class implements from `IDataErrorInfo` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`
Translations is an `ObservableCollection` of custom type "`LanguageValue`" with public properties Key and Value.

I had in my model `string this[string columnName]`, which works perfect with simple text boxes (outside ItemsControl), but how can make this works with my items? I've thight something like:

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
 get
 {
    string result = null;
    ...
    if (columnName == "Translations" || columnName == "ItemText")
    {
       if (Translations.All(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Value)))
          result = Properties.Resources.errMsgEnterName;
    }
...
```

But of course this didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, I'm giving you a full implementation but with just the "Value" property. Do the same with all other properties that you want to validate:

1.Translation Model with IDataErrorInfo interface implementation:

```
public class Translation : BindableBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return GetErrorForPropery(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public string Error { get; }

    private string GetErrorForPropery(string propertyName)
    {
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "Value":

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value))
                {
                    return "Please enter value";
                }

                return string.Empty;

            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

2.Initialize Translations in your ViewModel:

```
  public ObservableCollection<Translation> Translations { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Translations = new ObservableCollection<Translation>
        {
            new Translation {Value = "A"},
            new Translation (),
            new Translation {Value = "C"}
        };
    }
```

3.Xaml with ValidatesOnDataErrors on the Value TextBox:

```
  <ItemsControl x:Name="LanguageItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Translations, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5,2,5,2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="47*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="53*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ItemLabel" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

4.That will show a red box around the empty TextBox, if you want to display the error messeage when hovering overthe TextBox you need a tool tip:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:customControlLib="clr-namespace:CustomControlLib;assembly=CustomControlLib"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="LanguageItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Translations, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5,2,5,2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="47*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="53*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ItemLabel" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Good solution! But I don't need to show error when only one Value is empty. I want error when all of them are empty.